# `arrow::read_dataset('myfolder')` only read some folders/files

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I am trying to use the `arrow::read_dataset()` function to read datasets from a census with the following folder structure within the `mydatafolder`:

```
region1/per/per_state1.csv
...        /per_state2.csv
region1/hh/hh_state3.csv
...       /hh_state4.csv
region2/per/per_state5.csv
...        /per_state6.csv
region2/hh/hh_state7.csv
...       /hh_state8.csv
```

Note how within each region files are further grouped into hh (household level files) and per (person level files). I would like to read only the person files.

- How to instruct `arrow::read_dataset(mydatafolder,format='csv')` to only ready files in
  directories matching a pattern ("per" in this case)?
- Alternatively, is it possible to provide a string vector containing the folders/files to be read within `mydatafolder`?

obs: I am trying to avoid copying the data. If this functionality does not exist, I think would be a useful addition to the package. Besides more than one dataset in the same directory (per and hh in this example) there could be other files, such as documentation, that the user wants to ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be a pretty similar use case to the one mentioned in [arrow parquet partitioning, multiple datasets in same directory structure in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71355827/arrow-parquet-partitioning-multiple-datasets-in-same-directory-structure-in-r_).

Currently there is no support in `arrow::open_dataset()` for pattern matching which files are to be read in.  There is an open ticket on the project JIRA to implement this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-15943.  I've added a comment to report the fact that this is more user interest in implementing this feature.

In the meantime, it is possible to supply a vector of files to `open_dataset()`, though directory-based partitioning is lost here.

```r
library(arrow)

# set up example dataset
td <- tempfile()
dir.create(td)
write_dataset(mtcars, td, partitioning = "cyl", format = "csv")

# see the created files
list.files(td, recursive = TRUE)
#> [1] "cyl=4/part-0.csv" "cyl=6/part-0.csv" "cyl=8/part-0.csv"

# only read in the two files we want
mtcars_subset <- open_dataset(
  c(file.path(td, "cyl=4/part-0.csv"),file.path(td, "cyl=8/part-0.csv")),
  format = "csv"
)

# contains 2 files
mtcars_subset
#> FileSystemDataset with 2 csv files
#> mpg: double
#> disp: double
#> hp: int64
#> drat: double
#> wt: double
#> qsec: double
#> vs: int64
#> am: int64
#> gear: int64
#> carb: int64
```

Another potential future (at time of writing) alternative is by adding the filename as a column in the dataset and then filtering on its value; I am currently working on a PR to implement this, and am hoping to have it finished for version 10.0.0: https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/12826.

Comment: Thank you. Vector of files solution works and can be quite powerful when combined with `list.files(...,pattern='myregex')`. It can fix the cases of intertwined datasets (like this and the one in the other SO-question) as well as documentation files you need to ignore.

Comment: Adding the file name as a column (or virtual column) of the dataset can be quite useful. Especially in these old datasets, people saved space as they could, including embedding variables, such as geography divisions (state) in the filename.

Comment: @LucasMation You can pull out partitioning variables stored in directory names via [`partitioning`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/open_dataset.html#partitioning-1), though I'm not sure offhand if that extends to the file basename